# python fuzzy levenshtein ratio got early exit?

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I am trying to compare 100k strings each other. I cannot further reduce the problem size (i.e #strings in the set). I am using Levenshtein ratio to compare. If ratio is greater than 0.9, I want to store the 2 strings in a list. My question is about runtime optimization. Since 0.9 is my criteria, is there a way to pass this value to Levenshtein.ratio() and expect an early exit in the negative cases? If there exists a way to exit early, some runtime can be saved. Is it feasible in Levenshtein algorithm to get ratio early before calculating the complete distance(s).

E.g

```
import Levenshtein 
Levenshtein.ratio('lot of runtime','why not an early exit in this case by taking the intended ratio')
```

Is there something like:

```
Levenshtein.ratio('lot of runtime','why not an early exit in this case by taking the intended ratio', 0.9)
```

Comment: Why are you concerned with Python details if it is the algorithm that matters ? I have no idea how this module "Levenshtein" is implemented, but it is certainly possible to modify a dynamic programming implementation of it to stop before the complete processing.

Comment: I don't think so the current implementation supports it. You may wan't to fork it and change accordingly to support it, as it should be straight forward to implement.

Comment: alas, Levenshtein == `python-Levenshtein` which is written in C.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an early exit like you're postulating is possible.

The source code for the `Levenshtein` module is freely available, so you can add in the feature yourself.

There's another optimization you might wish to consider: the triangle inequality. If string A is 20% similar to string B, and string B is 90% similar to string C, you know that string A is not going to be 90% similar to string C. That would be impossible, so you don't have to actually compute the A-C Levenshtein distance at all.